# Set Request Validator of API Gateway by serverless

Tags: swagger, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I want to set Request Validator of API Gateway by serverless. I tried two different settings for the Request Validator. But, both methods have failed. I have summarized what I did, so please let me know if there is something wrong.

1. I write the API specification in swagger(OAS3.0). Therefore I tried to realize the setting of Request Validator using OAS extension. After I did `sls deploy` using below `swagger.yaml` and `serverless.yml`, None of the validate patterns described in `x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators` were added to the Request Validator options.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-request-validator.html

[image]

`swagger.yaml` is below:

```
openapi: 3.0.0

info:
  description: xxx
  version: '0.1'
  title: xxx API
x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators:
  body-only:
    validateRequestBody: true,
    validateRequestParameters: false
  except-body:
    validateRequestBody: false,
    validateRequestParameters: true
  all:
    validateRequestBody: true,
    validateRequestParameters: true
tags:
  - name: auth
    description: xxx
paths:
  /login:
    post:
      tags:
        - auth
      summary: xxx
      description: ''
      x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: all
      responses:
        '200':
          description: success
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/AuthResponse'
        '400':
          description: fail
          content:
            application/json
        '401':
          description: fail
          content:
            application/json
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/AuthRequest'
        required: true
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "200"
        uri: "arn:aws:apigateway:ap-northeast-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:function:xxx-api-dev-login/invocations"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        httpMethod: "POST"
        contentHandling: "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
        type: "aws_proxy"
```

My `serverless.yml` is below:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    RestApi :
      Type : AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
      Properties :
        Body : ${file(./swagger.yaml)}
    LoginApiToInvokeLambda:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
      DependsOn: LoginLambdaFunction
      Properties:
        FunctionName: xxx-ext-api-dev-login
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
        Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
```

2. I tried to realize the setting of Request Validator using `AWS::ApiGateway::RequestValidator`. After I did `sls deploy` using above `swagger.yaml` and below `serverless.yml`, the `all` described in `RequestValidatorAll` in `severless.yml` were added to the Request Validator options. But the default value of Request Validator was still NONE.
   [image]

```
resources:
  Resources:
    RestApi :
      Type : AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
      Properties :
        Body : ${file(./swagger.yaml)}
    LoginApiToInvokeLambda:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
      DependsOn: LoginLambdaFunction
      Properties:
        FunctionName: xxx-ext-api-dev-login
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
        Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
    RequestValidatorAll:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RequestValidator
      Properties:
        Name: all
        RestApiId:
          Ref: RestApi
        ValidateRequestBody: true
        ValidateRequestParameters: true
```

Comment: Same here! did you solved the issue?

Comment: You definitely need to create a custom validator (your second method). Can you post the cloudformation json of the login function? You can find it in .serverless/cloudformation-template-create-stack.json. 

As well as the cloudformation of the custom request validator you built.

Comment: Have you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the commas in your YAML.

i.e

```
x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators:  
 body-only:  
    validateRequestBody: true,  
    validateRequestParameters: false
  except-body:
    validateRequestBody: false,
    validateRequestParameters: true
  all:
    validateRequestBody: true,
    validateRequestParameters: true
```

should be

```
x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators:
  body-only:
    validateRequestBody: true
    validateRequestParameters: false
  except-body:
    validateRequestBody: false
    validateRequestParameters: true
  all:
    validateRequestBody: true
    validateRequestParameters: true
```

Once you do this the YAML will be valid and it should work.